# Move database files from one drive to another

Tags: sql-server, disk-space

I am running out of space in the C drive. I have plenty in the D or E drive.
How to I move database data from drive C to D or E?

Answer (score 2):

Check out those 2 blog posts on how to move DB data and log files

https://www.sqlshack.com/move-sql-database-files-mdf-ldf-another-location/

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/09/02/how-to-move-sql-server-mdf-and-ldf-files-interview-question-of-the-week-189/

Basic steps are:

- alter database's logical files' paths to point to new direction (in your case its D: or E:)
- bring database offline
- move physical database files to new location (D: or E:)
- bring  database online

So as you see, it is not complex, but does involve some downtime

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford an outage take a full backup. Then restore that backup using the [MOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_db_n_move_files) arguments. You can then delete the original DB files off the C drive.

Note that different files can be on different drives. For example, put the data files (mdf) on D and the log (ldf) on E. Then the work is spread over more spindles (and IO channels and drivers etc) so performance should be better. Spreading files like this is quite common.